# facebook - user changes password and invalidates the access token

Tags: facebook, oauth

Is any way to keep alive facebook access token also when user changes his password? Even with offline_access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is put in place to protect users in the event their account gets hacked or an app starts spamming.  They will need to re-authenticate with your application.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a how-to guide for handling this case:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/

You should probably check the full [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) document too